# C# IOException SerialPort.Write() -- The parameter is incorrect

Tags: c#, wpf, serial-port, virtual-serial-port

I am trying to write on a virtual serial port. This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading;

namespace MyWPFApp
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
/// 

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    static private SerialPort MyPort;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MyPort = new SerialPort("COM4");
        OpenMyPort();
    }

    private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!MyPort.IsOpen)
                MyPort.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error opening my port: {0}", ex.Message);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(MyPort.IsOpen);
        try
        {
            MyPort.Write("Hello");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error writing:", ex.Message);
        }

        MyPort.Close();

        Console.WriteLine(MyPort.IsOpen);
    }
}
}
```

This is my Output:

```
True
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in System.dll
Additional information: The parameter is incorrect.

The thread 0x195c has exited with code 259 (0x103).
Error writting:
False
The thread 0x19d4 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x1b18 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The program '[3080] MyWPFApp.vshost.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Why I got this error?The port is correctly opened and closed and the parameters are correct too. Does someone knows where is my error?

Comment: Check the parameters you are using when you open the serial port (baud rate, etc) are they correct for whatever hardware you are trying to communicate with? Are they supported by the serial port driver?

Comment: Your output doesn't make sense based on the code. There must be more going on here. Is there another thread, an event, or a timer? What line is the first exception happening on?

Comment: Virtual serial ports produce virtual errors.  Maybe it is upset that you didn't set the basic communication parameters, like Baudrate.  Maybe it is just junk software.

Comment: Finally I found the problem!! I was trying to connect through Virtual Serial Ports a WPF with a Serial Terminal. And I created a listening port type but I needed a bridge. Thanks a lot for your answers.